# How to build an object with a loop in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

Currently I have:

```
  newObject = {}
  for item in myArray
     newObject[item.id] = item.data
  newObject
```

As you can see i have an array of objects and I want to end up with an object which is keyed by one of the fields on the objects in the array with the values being the items in the array. i.e turn an array into a dict/keyed hash.

The above works but doesn't look very CoffeeScript to me. how do I do this in a nice CoffeeScript way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use **each** function from underscore library: http://underscorejs.org/#each

The above code would look like this:

```
newObject = {}
_.each myArray,(elem)->newObject[elem.id]=elem.data
newObject
```

The advantage is that underscore has other useful functionalities which can be used.

A simpler approach (without using underscore library), would be:

```
 newObject = {}
 newObject[elem.id]=elem.data for elem in myArray
 newObject
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of comprehension (second code snippet in Daniel Cioata answer), you can add destructuring assignment:

```
newObject = { }
newObject[id] = data for { id, data } in myArray
newObject
```